# Why does the Collection.equals() JavaDoc say it's not possible to correctly implement both List and Set?

Tags: java

The [API documentation for `Collection.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) says:

> The general contract for the `Object.equals` method states that equals
> must be symmetric (in other words, `a.equals(b)` if and only if
> `b.equals(a)`). The contracts for `List.equals` and `Set.equals` state that
> lists are only equal to other lists, and sets to other sets. Thus, a
> custom equals method for a collection class that implements neither
> the `List` nor `Set` interface must return `false` when this collection is
> compared to any list or set. **(By the same logic, it is not possible to
> write a class that correctly implements both the `Set` and `List`
> interfaces.)**

I have a question about the bolded sentence. Why can't I create a class like
`class SuperStringCollection implements List<String>, Set<String>`, the `equals` of which checks if the object is an instance of `SuperStringCollection` and (for simplicity's sake) stores elements in a `LinkedHashMap` (and probably also mirrors the elements in an `ArrayList` for the `listIterator`). What would make this an incorrect implementation?

Other references:

- [`List.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)
- [`Set.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: All Sets are Lists, but not all Lists are Sets, therefore not symmetric. Besides, why not just implement `Collection<String>`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer So what? This question asks not if a Set *is* a List or visa versus, but ask if something can be *both*. I agree with OP: It is possible, and simple, to implement both Set and List, ie an ordered Set. The equals method would just compare elements as if it were a List.

Comment: @Bohemian As the Javadoc says - _contracts for List.equals and Set.equals state that lists are only equal to other lists, and sets to other sets_... Sure, you can override equals to check `2 == 2`, or whatever, but that is not very user friendly. More precisely, List(1, 2, 2, 3) should not equal OrderedSet(1, 2, 3)

Comment: @OneCricketeer The javadoc is poorly worded. It’s saying that because equals() should be symmetric, a plain List will return false, but our new class would return true for that list. But that doesn’t mean it’s “not possible” to implement both Set and List. It just means our new class’s equals() misbehaves when mixed with plain Sets/Lists. So don’t mix them.

Comment: @Bohemian Java doesn't limit dual inheritance, sure. The wording is fine... It's not possible _to **correctly** implement_ both interfaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`List.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns true **if and only if** the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal.

[`Set.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns true if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set). This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface.

It's not possible to implement both interfaces and satisfy `List`'s "if and only if" constraint:

Let's say `a` were a `SuperStringCollection` and `b` were a `HashSet` containing matching elements.

- `b.equals(a)` will return `true` because `a` is a set and contains the same elements.
- By symmetry, `a.equals(b)` should also return `true`.
- However, `a.equals(b)` is required to return `false` because `List.equals()`'s contract says that `b` must be a `List`, which it is not.